# Vlookup varying column index number

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to change the column index number of vlookup but its showing `Colnum-14` for me at the cell I am looking at.

Is there something that I missed out? I am aware of the `match/index` formula, but I have to use the `vlookup`.

My code:

```
Dim Colnum As Integer
For Colnum = 15 To 16
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, Colnum + 1).Formula = "=iferror(vlookup(" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, 3).Address(False, True) & ",'Sheet2'!" & Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(20, 10)).Address & "," & "Colnum-14" & ",False), ""NA"")"
Next Colnum
```

Comment: Change `"Colnum-14"` to just `Colnum` in this part: `Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(20, 10)).Address & "," & "Colnum-14" & "`.

Comment: @TheLaughingMan I was posting the answer below when I took a phone call - so I has missed your comment.

Comment: @brettdj No issues. Sorely missed this tag so coming back. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are embedding a string *"Colnum-14"* rather than a variable `Colnum` for your lookup column. try

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, Colnum + 1).Formula = "=iferror(vlookup(" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, 3).Address(False, True) & ",'Sheet2'!" & Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(20, 10)).Address & "," & Colnum & ",False), ""NA"")"
```